# ConversionNotSupportedException from String to Custom Class

Tags: java, spring

My config file has the following bean

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
<bean id="testBean" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <property name="client" value="com.example.otherclass.Other"></property>
</bean>
```

And my class MyClass is

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {
Other client;


@Override
public void doIt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        System.out.println(client.getInfo());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public Other getClient() {
    return client;
}


public void setClient(Other client) {
    this.client = client;
}


}
```

Why am I getting

Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.example.otherclasses.Other] for property 'client': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the value of client to the string `com.example.otherclass.Other`.

You need to do something like:

```
<bean id="myOther" class="com.example.otherclass.Other">
</bean>

<bean id="testBean" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <property name="client" ref="myOther"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self explainatory. Your setter needs an `Other` object and you pass it the string `"com.example.otherclass.Other"`. Spring has some default converters, and could convert if to a `Class` object but not to an `Other` object.

If all you want is to initialize `client` attribute with a new `Other` object, you can use an anonymous(*) inner bean :

```
<bean id="testBean" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <property name="client">
        <bean class="com.example.otherclass.Other"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

(*) in fact, the bean will be given a name by Spring, but it is called *anonymous* since you normally cannot use it by name (you do not know the name).